# invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘const char**’

Tags: c++

```
void foo(const char **p)
{

}

int main()
{
    char *t;
    foo(&t);

    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't compile (http://ideone.com/2NHA08) on gcc (`error: invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘const char**’ [-fpermissive]`), but why? Conversion is an addition of `const`-ness, why can it fail?

Comment: `Conversion is an addition of const-ness, why can it fail?` Your assumption that it cannot is ill-formed. In fact you did not add `const`ness to the object you're passing -- the `char**`, but instead you tried to add `const`ness to the theoretical point-pointee, which is something _completely_ different. Notice that `const char**` is not the same as `char** const`.

Comment: The *pointer* can be implicitly converted to `const`, but not what it points to.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yet, we can convert `char*` to `const char*` just fine.

Comment: @jrok: At one level of indirection this can be enforced. At two, it cannot.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes. I didn't claim otherwise.

Comment: @jrok: And I didn't claim that you did!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough!

Comment: It's not clear to me that the C++ answers/solutions are correct for C.