# C++: char** to const char** conversion

Tags: c++, types

In C++, why is it not possible to pass a `char**` as an argument to a function that accepts `const char**` , when a conversion from `char*` to `const char*` is possible, as shown below

```
void f1(const char** a)
{

}

void f2(const char* b)
{

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   char* c;

   f1(&c); // doesn't work
   f2(c); //works

   return 0;
}
```

The compiler output is

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
test.cpp:15:10: error: invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'const char**' [-fpermissive]
test.cpp:1:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void f1(const char**)' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html

Comment: @zmb as always, the mighty C++ FAQ

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to protect contents on both levels of dereference of the pointer. With `const char**` you could actually modify contents on the 1st dereference.

```
char *tmp = "foo"; //Deprecated but it's ok for the example
void f1(const char** a)
{
  a[0] = tmp;     //this is legal
  a[0][1] = 'x';  //this is not
}
```

And this is most probably not intended. It should look like this:

```
char *tmp = "foo"; //Deprecated but it's ok for the example
void f1(char const* const* a)
{
  a[0] = tmp;    // this is not legal any more
  a[0][1] = 'x'; // this still upsets compiler
}
```

The compiler does not allow implicit conversion to such "partially" protected pointer types. Allowing such conversion could have nasty consequences as discussed in [`c++faq`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html) pointed out in comment by @zmb. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2463512/1133179) also cites how could you violate *constness* of an object if this was allowed, using `char` examples.

One can however implicitly convert to a "fully" protected pointer as shown in the 2nd code example so below code compiles.

```
void f1(char const* const* a){}
void f2(const char* b){}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   char* c;
   f1(&c); // works now too!
   f2(c);  // works
   return 0;
}
```

Actually there is a bunch of questions and answers on this matter lying around. E.g:

1. [invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘const char**’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959643/invalid-conversion-from-char-to-const-char?rq=1)
2. [Why am I getting an error converting a ‘float**’ to ‘const float**’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463473/why-am-i-getting-an-error-converting-a-float-to-const-float)

EDIT: I got the 1st example wrong by a bit. Thank for pointing it out!

Comment: When you know that there're multiple questions like this one, instead of answering it, flagging it as a dupe is more appropriate, no?

Comment: Since it has 6 up-votes maybe it has some original elements that I do not see. I also flagged it. Is it really so bad, that I assumed the other questions are similar but not exactly the same ? Even you said "possible duplicate", not a definite. Actually I took more time writing this comment than answering (sic!)

Comment: Of course not that bad, that's why I was not imposing, I was just asking, chill :) Oh and I didn't say `possible duplicate` that is done by SO automatically when someone flags it for the first time.

Comment: Also no accepted answer in linked questions present how to actually pass the data, or rather what is the right function declaration to pass `const char* argv[]` or eqivalents, at least from brief overview I made.

Comment: @luk32: I see your point and I upvoted you too

Comment: @legends2k lol, I didn't know it's automatic. Thanks for appreciating the effort.

Comment: @luk32 How would allowing the implicit conversion help in compiling your first example? Dereferencing `a` twice will still leave you with a const char.

Comment: @luk32 Your first example is incorrect.  The second line is invalid, not the first.  And you don't show what `foo` is.

Comment: @luk32 - please add the link to the C++FAQ from znb to your answer. After that, everything is said about this topic.

Comment: Even if this is a duplicate, this answer is better than the accepted one on the other question. I would be inclined to vote the other as a *anti-causal* duplicate of this...

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, that's my bad, but I am pretty sure that you can drop constness somehow, just my example is bad, but I do recall seeing or constructing such example. I need to figure it out. I will surely edit the answer.

Comment: @TobiasLangner I did not see the link before posting, also its 1st and top voted comment I do not feel the need to link it 2nd time since I didn't use it. It is visible enough IMO.

Comment: @luk32 Look in the C++ FAQ (one of the links).